# dh_make to build debian package need to manually hit <Enter> issue

Tags: linux, debian, prompt

when I run

```
dh_make --native
```

I get the following prompt:

```
Hit <Enter> to confirm
```

How do I escape this manual action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
yes | dh_make --native
```

`yes` should then confirm the prompt for you.

Answer (score 3):

The method of `yes | dh_make --native` no longer works.  The following error is produced:

```
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Instead, `dh_make` has added a `--yes` option to non-interactively run through any prompts.  You'll need to define the package class, e.g. `single, indep, library, python`

```
dh_make --native --indep --yes
```

[DH_MAKE(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dh-make/dh_make.8.en.html)